# dbExpress design question

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

Does anybody know (or care to make a suppostion as to) why TSqlDataset has a *commandtext* property (string) whereas TSqlQuery has a *sql* property (tstrings)?

Consider the sql statement

```
select id, name from
table
order by name
```

If I use a TSqlQuery, then I can change the table name in the query dynamically by accessing sql[1], but if I am using a TSqlDataset (as I have to if I need a bidrectional dataset, the dataset is connected to a provider and thence to a tclientdataset), I have to set the commandtext string literally. Whilst the above example is trivial, it can be a problem when the sql statement is much more involved.

**Update**: 
Judging by the comments and answers so far, it seems that I was misunderstood. I don't care very much for improving the runtime performance of the components (what does one millisecond matter when the query takes one second) but I do care about the programmer (ie me) and the ability to maintain the program. In real life, I have the following query which is stored in a TSqlQuery:

```
select dockets.id, dockets.opendate, customers.name, statuses.statname,
dockets.totalcost, dockets.whopays, dockets.expected, dockets.urgent,
(dockets.totalcost - dockets.billed) as openbill,
(dockets.totalcost - dockets.paid) as opencost,
location.name as locname, dockets.attention,
statuses.colour, statuses.disporder, statuses.future, dockets.urgcomment
from location, statuses, dockets left join customers
on dockets.customer = customers.id
where dockets.location = location.id
and dockets.status = statuses.id
```

I haven't counted the number of characters in the string, but I'm sure that there are more than 255, thus precluding storing the query in a simple string. In certain circumstances, I want to filter the amount of data being displayed by adding the line 'and statuses.id = 3' or 'and customers.id = 249'. If the query were stored as TStrings, then I could add to the basic query the dummy line 'and 1 = 1', and then update this line as needed. But the query is one long string and I can't easily access the end of it.

What I am currently doing (in lieu of a better solution) is creating another TSqlDataSet, and setting its commandtext to the default TSqlDataSet's commandtext whilst appending the extra condition.

Comment: If you consider the time spent in changing the SQL text statement regarding the execution time of the statement itself, changing the whole SQL string is not a concern. In all cases, the whole SQL statement will be sent to the background DB driver, so both methods are equals. (even setting SQL[1] may be a bit slower, if `ParamCheck=true` - see da-soft answer) If you want something faster, do not use dbExpress but a direct database access component.

Comment: 1) Sorry, but that is not 1ms. Just believe ... 
2) 255 is not a limit for Delphi strings, since Delphi2.
3) You can effectively use as TStrings, as String. My answer has everything for that.

Comment: Just in case da-soft didn't say it clearly enough; The 255 character limit on strings applied to Delphi 1, in 1995.  It hasn't applied any more to Delphi since version 2.0, in 1996, and that was over 15 years ago!  Multiline Strings can be edited in the delphi property inspector, if they have a designtime "helper" registered, which in this case, for TSqlDataSet.CommandText, is already  there for you to use. Just click the ellipsis button in the property inspector and you get a nice SQL editor helper dialog box. It's not RapidSQL or Toad, but it's better than using a 1" wide string property.

Answer (score 5):

1) `TSQLQuery` is rather for compatibility with BDE TQuery. And BDE TQuery has `SQL: TStrings` property. `TSQLDataSet` is what supposed to be used for new applications.

2) Although `SQL: TStrings` is usefull for some tasks, it is also error prone. Often programmers forget to clear SQL property before filling again. Also if your query is a big one, the filling of SQL may lead to performance degradation. Because on each `SQL.Add(...)` call dbExpress code parses query when ParamCheck is True. That may be solved by using `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate` or setting ParamCheck to False. But note, setting ParamCheck to False stops automatic parameters creation.

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.BeginUpdate;
try
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM');
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('Orders');
finally
  SQLQuery1.SQL.EndUpdate;
end;
```

`CommandText` does not have such issues.

3) You can use `Format` function for building a dynamic SQL string:

```
var
  sTableName: String;
...
sTableName := 'Orders';
SQLDataSet1.CommandText := Format('select * from %s', [sTableName]);
```

4) Other data access libraries, like [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/), have [macro variables](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Preprocessing_Command_Text.html), simplifying dynamic query text building. For example:

```
ADQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM &TabName';
ADQuery1.Macros[0].AsRaw := 'Orders';
ADQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: "the filling of SQL may lead to performance degradation" was intriguing... and it's right: the `TSQLQuery.QueryChange` method is called whenever SQL.Add is executed. So it's a good idea to set `ParamCheck=false`

Answer (score -1):

I would have to say that the TSqlQuery uses TStrings (TWideStrings in Delphi 2010) because it is much more flexible.

Suppose your query was:
`Select
Item1,
Item2,
Item3,
Item4
FROM MyTable`

- It's a lot easier to read
- You can copy and paste into an external query tool and it stays formatted
- It's easy to comment out sections

`Select
Item1,
/*
Item2,
Item3,
*/
Item4
FROM MyTable`

- You can easily add items

`Select
Item1,
Item2,
Item2a,
Item2b,
Item3,
Item3a,
Item3b,
Item4
FROM MyTable`

Try doing that to a contiguous set of characters that goes on forever in one long line with no line breaks inside an edit window that is always to small for viewing that doesn't allow for wrapped text etc. etc. etc.

Just $0.02.

Comment: I quite agree. I was asking, though, what might have been the design issues which seem to have chosen a string over a list of strings.

Comment: Wrong. Just click ellipsis button `[...]` to edit the property in a multiline edit field. Just because TStrings just shows `(Strings)` in the top level view is no reason to think TStrings are better.

Comment: I do click the ellipsis button when editing the string at design time. I am asking about runtime manipulation of the query, which is harder to do when the query is stored as a string, as opposed to a stringlist.